# How to add entire vs code local project to github

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I have a local VS Code project where I have 7 branches and several commits, I need to upload my project to GitHub, I had used 'Add Remote' command in VS Code but it uploads only that branch which is currently opened, is there any git command to upload entire branches at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To push all branches up to GitHub at once (instead of pushing each one individually):

Open your command line, navigate to the project root, and run `git push --all origin` (assuming “origin” is the name of your remote).

Answer (score 0):

While remote support was added in VSCode 1.33, as part of [PR -- Pull Request -- 60640](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/60640), [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/60640#issuecomment-449900754) illustrates that a `git push --all origin` is not yet supported by the GUI itself.
Hence the recommendation of using the command-line equivalent to push everything from one repository.